# Clang doesnt recognize std::all_of in <algorithm>

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, freebsd

while compiling in our test environment i encountered the following problem:

Despite the already working windows our build failed on Freebsd 9 with the following error message:

```
error: no member named 'all_of' in namespace 'std'
```

Given that i added -std=c++11 to our Cmake flags i wonder why this is not working.

```
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: i386-portbld-freebsd9.1
Thread model: posix
```

Heres the function

```
#include <algorithm>
...
inline bool is_positive_number(const std::string & str)
{
    if (str.empty())
            return false;

    return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isdigit);
}
```

Installer Log from pkg install clang34

```
Installing libexecinfo: 1.1_3
Installing llvm34: 3.4_1
Installing clang34: 3.4_2
```

Help appreciated i thought this function was implemented some ages ago but apparently im using it wrong or maybe i totally misunderstood something both is possible im quite new to clang.

Edit: Details of the process.

```
Selected GCC installation:
 "/usr/local/llvm34/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple i386-portbld-freebsd9.1 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu i486 -target-linker-version 2.17.50 -v -v -g -coverage-file /home/source/release/server/game/CMakeFiles/game_r4708M_32.dir/src/main.cpp.o -resource-dir /usr/local/llvm34/bin/../lib/clang/3.4 -D "__SVN_VERSION__=\"\"" -I /home/source/release/server/game/../../extern/include/boost -I /home/source/release/server/game/../../extern/include -I /home/source/release/server/game/../libmysql/mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-src/output/freebsd/include -I /home/source/release/server/game/../liblua/include -I /home/source/release/server/game/../libdevil -internal-isystem /usr/include/c++/4.2 -internal-isystem /usr/include/c++/4.2/backward -Wno-invalid-source-encoding -W -Wno-invalid-source-encoding -W -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/source/release/server/game -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 237 -mstackrealign -fobjc-runtime=gnustep -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o CMakeFiles/game_r4708M_32.dir/src/main.cpp.o -x c++ /home/source/release/server/game/src/main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 3.4 based upon LLVM 3.4 default target i386-portbld-freebsd9.1
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/c++/4.2"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/c++/4.2"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/c++/4.2/backward"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/source/release/server/game/../../extern/include/boost
 /home/source/release/server/game/../../extern/include
 /home/source/release/server/game/../libmysql/mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-src/output/freebsd/include
 /home/source/release/server/game/../liblua/include
 /home/source/release/server/game/../libdevil
 /usr/include/c++/4.2
 /usr/include/c++/4.2/backward
 /usr/local/llvm34/bin/../lib/clang/3.4/include
```

After switching to "-stdlib=libc++" as suggested by Steve Wills, I assume its selecting the right include path (v1) but its still not found or conflicted.

```
 clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: i386-portbld-freebsd9.1
Thread model: posix
Selected GCC installation:
 "/usr/local/llvm34/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple i386-portbld-freebsd9.1 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu i486 -target-linker-version 2.17.50 -v -v -g -coverage-file /home/source/release/server/game/CMakeFiles/game_r4708M_32.dir/src/main.cpp.o -resource-dir /usr/local/llvm34/bin/../lib/clang/3.4 -D "__SVN_VERSION__=\"\"" -I /home/source/release/server/game/../../extern/include/boost -I /home/source/release/server/game/../../extern/include -I /home/source/release/server/game/../libmysql/mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-src/output/freebsd/include -I /home/source/release/server/game/../liblua/include -I /home/source/release/server/game/../libdevil -internal-isystem /usr/include/c++/v1 -Wno-invalid-source-encoding -W -Wno-invalid-source-encoding -W -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/source/release/server/game -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 237 -mstackrealign -fobjc-runtime=gnustep -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o CMakeFiles/game_r4708M_32.dir/src/main.cpp.o -x c++ /home/source/release/server/game/src/main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 3.4 based upon LLVM 3.4 default target i386-portbld-freebsd9.1
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/c++/4.2"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/source/release/server/game/../../extern/include/boost
 /home/source/release/server/game/../../extern/include
 /home/source/release/server/game/../libmysql/mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-src/output/freebsd/include
 /home/source/release/server/game/../liblua/include
 /home/source/release/server/game/../libdevil
 /usr/include/c++/v1
 /usr/include/c++/4.2
 /usr/include/c++/4.2/backward
 /usr/local/llvm34/bin/../lib/clang/3.4/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
In file included from /home/source/release/server/game/src/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/source/release/server/game/src/stdafx.h:12:
/home/source/release/server/game/src/../../common/utils.h:120:14: error: no member named 'all_of' in namespace 'std'
```

Comment: Maybe some mixture between the stdlib of clang and the GCC ones?

Comment: That could indeed be true but how do i check this kind of behaviour ?

Comment: Preprocess and inspect the result.  gcc headers are sometimes installed with the gcc version number in the path.

Comment: Well i included some informations but i still cant get something out of it. Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: Does adding "-stdlib=libc++" help?

Comment: If I'm not wrong that paths (`/usr/include/c++/4.2`) are of GCC 4.2, not clang. Thats why the function is not found: GCC4.2 doesn't target C++11 (At least completely)

Comment: I added the new result include path seems fine now but still throwing the message due to some conflict maybe ?

Comment: Now the obvious question: Is `utils.h` actually including `algorithm`?

Comment: Well as i said the path is different now its v1 (but thats empty as i just saw oO) instead of the other 4.2 one but this one is still there maybe thats causing errors.

Comment: V1 is the clang stdlib path

Comment: i cant get libc++ to run for some reason :S

Answer (score 1):

This error is likely a result of a missing:

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 )
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that there is something in your Cmake setup.
Or maybe that Cmake isn't very good at recognizing Clang?

The following minimal example;

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool is_positive_number(const std::string & str);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    is_positive_number("12");
}

bool is_positive_number(const std::string & str)
{
    if (str.empty())
            return false;

    return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isdigit);
}
```

compiles without warnings using `c++` or `clang++` without any special directives;

```
c++ -Wall foo.cpp
```

For reference (reformatted for convenience):

```
c++ -### foo.cpp
FreeBSD clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final 197956) 20140216
Target: x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/bin/c++" "-cc1" "-triple" "x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0" 
"-emit-obj" "-mrelax-all" "-disable-free" "-disable-llvm-verifier" 
"-main-file-name" "foo.cpp" "-mrelocation-model" "static" 
"-mdisable-fp-elim" 
"-masm-verbose" "-mconstructor-aliases" "-munwind-tables" 
"-target-cpu" "x86-64" "-resource-dir" "/usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.4" 
"-internal-isystem" "/usr/include/c++/v1" "-fdeprecated-macro" 
"-fdebug-compilation-dir" "/home/rsmith/tmp" "-ferror-limit" "19" 
"-fmessage-length" "105" "-mstackrealign" "-fobjc-runtime=gnustep" 
"-fcxx-exceptions" "-fexceptions" "-fdiagnostics-show-option" 
"-fcolor-diagnostics" "-vectorize-slp" "-o" "/tmp/foo-206692.o" 
"-x" "c++" "foo.cpp"
"/usr/bin/ld" "--eh-frame-hdr" "-dynamic-linker" 
"/libexec /ld-elf.so.1" "--hash-style=both" "--enable-new-dtags"
"-o" "a.out" "/usr/lib/crt1.o" "/usr/lib/crti.o" 
"/usr/lib/crtbegin.o" "-L/usr/lib" "/tmp/foo-206692.o" 
"-lc++" "-lm" "-lgcc" "--as-needed" "-lgcc_s" "--no-as-needed"
"-lc" "-lgcc" "--as-needed" "-lgcc_s" "--no-as-needed" 
"/usr/lib/crtend.o" "/usr/lib/crtn.o"
```

Notice how this only uses `"-internal-isystem" "/usr/include/c++/v1"`, while your invocation also uses `/usr/include/c++/4.2"` (which is from the old GCC c++ version 4.2).

Answer (score 0):

to run all_of function you need c++11 complier
if you run the program in codeblocks then go to
`setting --> compliers --> c++11 ISO c++ language standard [-std=c++11]`
it will surely work
thank you good luck